# Highlight active page in a table row using views

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a drupal 7 view that is outputting the titles of nodes which is in table form.

```
<table class="views-table cols-0" thmr="thmr_80">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd views-row-first">
      <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>          
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
        <a href="#" class="active">Link 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Drupal gets me close by adding "active" class to the link (Link 2), but I would like it for the entire row (TR).

I saw another [question like this one asked for an unordered list](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46104/how-to-highlight-active-teaser-in-views), but I tried that code and it didn't work. Maybe a little tweaking needed?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the answer using jquery. Hope this will help others who need it. Just add this code into the top of the page template and it will create the active class for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function() {
   $('.views-table a.active').closest('tr').addClass('active_row');
});

</script>
```

Remember to change the "views-table" to match your own table.